# Scrambled eggs for a buffet

Tags: eggs, scrambled-eggs

At our cafe we will begin offering a Saturday brunch buffet. I would like to do scrambled eggs and am thinking that they would be best cooked in a hotel pan in the oven. Any advice for this method of cooking?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi and welcome - do you have specific concerns about the method? Have you tried it before? As written, this is a fairly broad question and it's likely to get closed.

Comment: How many portions of eggs are you cooking? Are they pre-cracked or are you going to be cracking dozens of eggs yourself? Do you have access to a large steamer?

Comment: The problem w/ cooking in the oven is stirring.  You'll end up with a frittatta unless you're in there stirring it every so often.

Answer (score 3):

I cooked a brunch for a fairly high end restaurant when I was younger. They had us cook the eggs in a buffet pan on top of the griddle/grill. We used pre-cracked eggs in a carton and folded constantly until they were done. Then we would transfer them into a fresh buffet pan before setting them out. They did it this way because it presented better than just baking in the oven. They look more like the scrambled eggs you get per order this way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a viable way of cooking large amounts of eggs. From experience, I can tell you that a major concern is preventing the eggs from overcooking. They can be cooked in an oven if they're watched carefully, and it may help to cover them. It works even better to cook them in a combi oven, as heat can be transferred faster at a lower temperature. 
When the eggs are cooked, you will have what is basically a large omelet, so usually you'd chop them up with a spatula before serving.

Answer (score 1):

First do not scrimp on the ingredients.  You need butter, not alternatives.  you can cook quite a lot of scrambled eggs in one go (about 20 portions), remembering to take them off the heat before fully 'set'.  I assume you have overhead heat lamps on your buffet, this will also cook your eggs.  You/your staff will need to keep an eye on your eggs here, a quick turning of them in the serving dish will keep them looking fresh for your customers.  But the only way to really serve large quantities of good quality scrambled eggs is to keep making smaller batches and keep them coming!  Hope it goes well